# Multi Resolution graphic for ios 4 and ios 5

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, resolution

I have used cocos2d-x to develop a game for iPhone 4, iPhone 4s, iPhone 5 with different screen sizes (3.5 inch and 4 inch)

First, my resource are designed for iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s with 3.5 inch screen size.

So if I want to use for iPhone 5 with 4 inch screen size. what should I do?

Comment: I think you mean iPhone 4 and iPhone 5? The iOS Version has nothing to do with screen size.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is that using `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToUI]` and not using it. 
If you want to place align top, using `convertToUI` or else using normal `ccp(x, y)`.
Also you need to write a method to resize the area that need to fill up the screen;

Another good option is to use the CocosBuilder to create the user interface;
Can know more at the following URL:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/23996/introduction-to-cocosbuilder